# is there any function to know a key of keyboard is pressed or not?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a console application with Qt Creator and  I must know if a key is pressed (or not) and make the true decision,   but how could I know?

should i write a function to do this purpose ?

Comment: It depends on what you need the key presses for. For instance, keyboard shortcuts are handled in quite a different way than, say, game controls, etc...
Also, did you read the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`QKeyEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html) and google for some tutorials [like this one](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/qtClasses.php?item=QKeyEvent).

Answer (score 2):

How to do it depends on the operating system. For example, when you press the P key while playing a video game on your Windows PC, the game pauses. How does the game know to pause? The game is monitoring the state of the P key in a loop. Like all keys, the P key has two states (up or down). When the state changes, the key has been pressed or released. Passive keystroke loggers work this way, except they monitor all the keys, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QShortcut`. Refer to the Qt doc for usage